# Как работает .htaccess для подключения через php?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

Подключаю через `include` на странице какие-то файлы, например:

```
include 'fragments/portal-a.html';
include 'fragments/portal-b.html';
include 'fragments/portal-c.html';
```

Можно ли настроить .htaccess так, чтобы php обращался к этим файлам, понимая их под под именами:

```
include '1';
include '2';
include '3';
```

?

Эта переадресация работает, если переходить по этим ссылкам. Может ли она работать для php? Или для этой задачи используется что-то другое?

Comment: Htaccess никак не влияет на PHP. А зачем вы этого хотите? Вам лень печатать длинные строчки или какая-то другая причина?

Comment: можете добавить функцию, которая будет мапить вам 1 в `,,,/portal-a.html` и использовать при вызове. Либо симлинки в ФС сделать, что костыль лютый. Если контент надо вывести из этих файлов на страницу, то можете сделать функцию, которая примет массив`[a,b,c,]` и вернет контент, который вы выведите.

Answer (score 2):

.htaccess - конфигурация уровня сервера Apache. PHP о ней ничего не знает.
Данный вопрос через этот файл конфигурации не решить.

но вы можете сделать некую функцию например, которая будет делать инклуды по вашему образцу, например

```
<?php
function includeTemplate(int $num) {
    include 'fragments/portal-' . $num. '.html';
}

includeTemplate(1);
includeTemplate(2);
includeTemplate(3);
```

это если например имена файлов
fragments/portal-1.html
fragments/portal-2.html
fragments/portal-3.html

но ничего не мешает добавить обработку в ту самую функцию и смотреть например что за аргумент передали и исвходя из этого подключать требуемый файл